# How queue multiple script calls in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I have a PHP script that opens an XML document, gets the DOM and modifies it, and then it and it works correctly. I use it in custom WordPress plugin.
As I understand when multiple users or a user use this function at same time, and simultaneously the XML file will be empty of elements and there is just `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Does it relate to asynchronous behavior of PHP functions? how can I solve this problem? should I queue the function? how?

The code is:

```
function ym_update_product_xml($p_id, $p_name, $p_status, $p_exerpt, $p_price, $p_inventory){

 if($p_id){
  $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $xml->formatOutput = true; 
  $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  $xml->load(YDE_INC . 'all_products.xml');
  $ym_all_products = $xml->documentElement;
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

  $_product_name = $xpath->query('/ym_all_products/product[@id="' . $p_id . '"]/product_name');
  $_product_status = $xpath->query('/ym_all_products/product[@id="' . $p_id . '"]/product_status');
  $_product_exerpt = $xpath->query('/ym_all_products/product[@id="' . $p_id . '"]/product_exerpt');
  $_product_price = $xpath->query('/ym_all_products/product[@id="' . $p_id . '"]/product_price');
  $_product_invt = $xpath->query('/ym_all_products/product[@id="' . $p_id . '"]/product_invt');

  if( $p_name != null ){$_product_name->item(0)->nodeValue = $p_name;}
  if( $p_status != null ){$_product_status->item(0)->nodeValue = $p_status;}
  if( $p_exerpt != null ){$_product_exerpt->item(0)->nodeValue = $p_exerpt;}
  if( $p_price != null ){$_product_price->item(0)->nodeValue = $p_price;}
  if( $p_inventory != null ){$_product_invt->item(0)->nodeValue = $p_inventory;}

  $xml->save(YDE_INC . 'all_products.xml');

    return true;
    }else{
   return false;
  }
}
```

the function works correctly.

Comment: Sounds like you should not use a file for this problem. Also, I doubt this is related to Wordpress after all, so please remove the tag

Comment: File systems don't handle multi-user concurrency like databases do.  And adding support for that is *non-trivial*.  (Likely involving writing to something like a message queue and having a separate application which de-queues messages to perform the operations.  Which makes the entire operation very asynchronous and changes your whole structure.)  It sounds like you should be using a database instead.  Does your data *need* to be stored in a file instead of a database?  Why?

Comment: A file is not a good solution to sharing data amongst multiple users, if they can all be editing it at the same time. This sort of thing is generally what people use databases for, I would think (although admittedly you did not actually explain what the business process is, or the reason for using an XML file specifically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is not related to the asynchronous behavior of PHP functions, but rather to the concurrent access of the XML file by multiple users or simultaneous requests. When multiple users execute the function at the same time, there can be a race condition where one user's changes overwrite another user's changes, resulting in an empty XML file with only the XML declaration.

To solve this problem, you can implement a locking mechanism to ensure that only one user can modify the XML file at a time. One approach is to use file locking in PHP. Here's an updated version of your code that includes a locking mechanism:

```
function ym_update_product_xml($p_id, $p_name, $p_status, $p_exerpt, $p_price, $p_inventory) {
    if ($p_id) {
        $xmlFile = YDE_INC . 'all_products.xml';
        $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $xml->formatOutput = true;
        $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

        // Acquire an exclusive lock on the XML file
        $fileHandle = fopen($xmlFile, 'r+');
        if (flock($fileHandle, LOCK_EX)) {
            $xml->load($xmlFile);
            $ym_all_products = $xml->documentElement;
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

            $_product_name = $xpath->query('/ym_all_products/product[@id="' . $p_id . '"]/product_name');
            $_product_status = $xpath->query('/ym_all_products/product[@id="' . $p_id . '"]/product_status');
            $_product_exerpt = $xpath->query('/ym_all_products/product[@id="' . $p_id . '"]/product_exerpt');
            $_product_price = $xpath->query('/ym_all_products/product[@id="' . $p_id . '"]/product_price');
            $_product_invt = $xpath->query('/ym_all_products/product[@id="' . $p_id . '"]/product_invt');

            if ($p_name != null) {
                $_product_name->item(0)->nodeValue = $p_name;
            }
            if ($p_status != null) {
                $_product_status->item(0)->nodeValue = $p_status;
            }
            if ($p_exerpt != null) {
                $_product_exerpt->item(0)->nodeValue = $p_exerpt;
            }
            if ($p_price != null) {
                $_product_price->item(0)->nodeValue = $p_price;
            }
            if ($p_inventory != null) {
                $_product_invt->item(0)->nodeValue = $p_inventory;
            }

            $xml->save($xmlFile);

            // Release the lock and close the file handle
            flock($fileHandle, LOCK_UN);
            fclose($fileHandle);

            return true;
        } else {
            // Failed to acquire the lock, handle the error
            fclose($fileHandle);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this updated code, the flock function is used to acquire an exclusive lock (LOCK_EX) on the XML file before loading and modifying it. If the lock is successfully acquired, the changes are made, and then the lock is released (LOCK_UN). If the lock cannot be acquired, the function returns false to indicate an error occurred.

By using file locking, you ensure that only one user can modify the XML file at a time, preventing concurrent modifications and potential data loss.

Comment: Thank a lot, your update works.

Comment: This looks like it was copied from ChatGPT